# Inkscape: Changing default canvas size

Tags: inkscape

Is there a way to customize the default canvas size in Inkscape?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Since Inkscape 1.0 there's an easy way to do this:

1. Create a new blank document (*File* → *New*).
2. Open the *File* → *Document Properties…* dialog and set your canvas size (and any other settings you want to change the defaults for, like display units, guides, grids, background color, etc.) the way you want it to be.
3. Now open the ***File* → *Save Template…*** dialog, enter whatever you want as the name of the template, make sure the "**Set as default template**" checkbox is checked and press *Save*.

<sup>Credit to Spencer Russell for pointing this out. Please go upvote [their answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/144910) if you found this useful.</sup>

---

The older way, which should still work, is to start with a blank document, change the canvas size to whatever you want, and then save the document as `templates/default.svg` in your Inkscape config directory (`~/.config/inkscape` on Linux).  Then restart Inkscape, and it should open with whatever document you just saved as the default template.

You can also create your own document templates (which you can access from the *File* → *New from Template* dialog) by saving files with other names in that directory.

(Ps. If your interface language is set to something other than English, you may need to save the default template as `default.xx.svg` instead of `default.svg`, where `xx` stands for the [two-letter ISO language code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_639-1) of your language.  This should not be necessary in recent versions of Inkscape, however.)

Comment: In windows you can find the Inkscape config directory in `%appdata%` (type that in the *Name* field of the *Save* dialog and press *Enter*).

Comment: The full path under Linux and OS X is `~/.config/inkscape/templates/default.svg`, for those too lazy to combine two path fragments manually. ;)

Comment: I don't have inkscape in my `./config` directory, should I add it?

Comment: @Hilberto1: It should be there if you've used Inkscape before (or at least if you've ever edited your preferences in Inkscape), unless your Inkscape is configured (e.g. via [environment variables](https://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php?title=Environment_variables)) to use some other config directory. If it doesn't exist, creating it shouldn't do any harm, but the fact that Inkscape hasn't created it already *might* mean that your Inkscape installation is actually set up to look for its configuration files somewhere else.

Comment: @Hilberto1: However, it turns out that nowadays there's also a much easier way to do this that doesn't require finding the config directory. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 16):

A short answer for Windows users:

- Open any document, you may want to start from the default document or another template using `File | Templates`.
- Modify any `Document Properties` (Shift-Ctrl-D) you want on the document using tabs, This is where you find the document size, the size units, the grid (default) units, etc,
- Select user interface options (like snap option buttons),
- Add any default objects in the document if you need it,
- Etc.

Save this document as `%appdata%\inkscape\templates\default.svg`.
This folder is actually `C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\templates` in Windows 7, and is empty.

---

I'll always be surprised by a software made for the entire world which is configured to use imperial units by default, and which has a site explaining how to change the units by referring to Linux. Nearly the entire world uses the SI units and Windows... But that's free and open source software, so this small annoyance is largely balanced by the rest.

Comment: At the moment, the built-in defaults are metric and A4 paper. The whole thing ought to be a regional setting.

Comment: I'll always be surprised that the linux community wants people to learn about magic files and configurations instead of just including a simple program option.

Comment: @A.R. True! In the Linux community there are kernel developers pure system engineers, a good thing, and UI ('distribution') developers who should think about it as a tool given to users for their own needs. But they think about it as a goal. Over the last 20 years, I tried 5 or 10 times to use the most advanced Linux distributions, learning by hundredths of hours, to see this is still a second-rate product for desktop users. With no surprise UI-less Linux is successful in datacenters, and [Linux desktop is now right dead](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2009/09/21/linuxcon_2009_sutor_keynote/).

Comment: @mins  It's really too bad.  Linux has a lot of great things to offer, except a useful interface. :)

Comment: @A.R.and except security: While Windows is most denigrated for [its supposed large number of vulnerabilities](https://www.cvedetails.com/product/17153/Microsoft-Windows-7.html?vendor_id=26), actually [Debian kernel](https://www.cvedetails.com/vendor/23/Debian.html) is not better (and that's only the kernel).

Answer (score 4):

On top of the other reply, you can save much more changes to templates: snapping options, guides etc. [This article](http://libregraphicsworld.org/blog/entry/using-templates-in-inkscape) explains that in details.

Comment: This is a link-only answer. Please include relevant details from the linked page here.

Answer (score 3):

It's even easier than that. Go under **File > Save Template…**, pick any name you want for your new template in the pop-up window and check the "**Set as default template**" checkbox before clicking *Save*. That's it.