# Inkscape - Permanently Change Default Document Background Color

Tags: color, inkscape, background, document-setup

Just like the title says, does anyone know of a way to PERMANENTLY change the default document background color in Inkscape? I know you can do it on a by-document basis in the "Document Properties" dialog, but I'm looking for a way to make it so that it defaults to a particular color whenever I open up a new document.

Comment: Did you try [changing your default template](http://www.shmoggo.com/articles/inkscape-how-to-change-default-document-properties/)? ([other related question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5830/inkscape-changing-default-canvas-size))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to your default file `default.svg` when interface has translated you have to change a file `default_XX.svg`

eg: `default_pt_BR.svg`

on the linux the default folder is `/usr/share/inkscape/templates/`

> Remember, doing it as root user!

on windows `C:\Program Files (x86)\Inkscape\share\inkscape\templates\`.

open the svg file with a text editor and change the line where is      `pagecolor="#ffffff"`

Comment: Thanks Guilherme! My default documents still weren't looking right, but this pointed me in the right direction.

Some things I found out:
1) Be sure to change the "inkscape:pageopacity" value to 1; otherwise the document background will still look white (transparent). 2) You can also just set up your document how you want default documents to be, and then save it as "default.svg" in "~/.config/inkscape/templates", and Inkscape will default to that instead. This ensures you will keep your default document settings in case of an Inkscape upgrade. Anyway, thanks again for the help Guilherme!

Comment: How could you set it to Checkerboard pattern?

Comment: Nevermind, you said how to and it works.  I did this: Make a new document. Change the DocProps > BG=checker.  Save as default.svg, and overwrite the specified default.svg in the Inkscape folder.

Comment: I installed Inkscape from the Windows Store; I found the template at `C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\25415Inkscape.Inkscape_1.2.0.0_x64__9waqn51p1ttv2\VFS\ProgramFilesX64\Inkscape\share\inkscape\templates\default.svg`.