# Inkscape on Windows: How to change the default unit to pixels for new documents?

Tags: inkscape, windows, configuration

Creating this question, and providing the answer as well.

On new documents created with the default template, the default unit is either in (US) or mm (Europe).

[image]

As I work mostly on documents which are displayed on screens, I'm mostly interested in having them measured in pixels (the export to png format is also facilitated).

How to change the unit of the default document?

Answer (score 19):

Changing the unit used in a new document is done by configuring a default template:

In Windows the default template is a document that is saved as:

```
%appdata%\inkscape\templates\default.svg.
```

This folder is actually:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\inkscape\templates
```

in Windows 7, and is empty.

See more details on [this answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5830/inkscape-changing-default-canvas-size/74831#74831) related to changing the default size.

Comment: For macOS and Linux it's `~/.config/inkscape/templates/default.svg`.

Comment: With my version 0.92 on Windows 64bit, the file appear to have been relocated to `C:\Program Files\Inkscape\share`

Comment: @EntarraDe'Lacord: Thanks for the update. By the way, `C:\Program Files\` in a correctly configured Windows is not writable without administrator privileges. This folder is supposed to only contain application binaries and permanent files. To write (and update) files removing the [UAC protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) is required. A not so good idea when connected to the Internet.

Comment: @mins you don't need to completely remove the UAC protection: Run the editor you're opening the file with (Inkscape I guess) as Administrator and you can write to the file in question.

Comment: @EntarraDe'Lacord Thanks! For future reference, on 1.0 beta, it's at `{inkscapeRoot}\share\inkscape\templates\`

Comment: For Linux (0.92) it's `/usr/share/inkscape/templates/` and is the default for all users. You can copy `/usr/share/inkscape/templates/default.svg` to `~/.config/inkscape/templates/` and edit the copy. If that doesn't work maybe you need to copy one of the many localized svgs instead.

Comment: Please note that if you set the environment variable `INKSCAPE_PROFILE_DIR` under Windows, the path will be relative to that folder, e.g. `%INKSCAPE_PROFILE_DIR%\templates\default.svg`.