# Setting the Default Units to px for Inkscape on MacOS?

Tags: inkscape

[There's an answer for how to do this on Windows here](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/74833/inkscape-on-windows-how-to-change-the-default-unit-to-pixels-for-new-documents).  How do we do it on a MacBook (MacOS)?

The comments in the other question mention that the configuration location is under ~/.config/inkscape ... however it seems this is different with the newer version of Inkscape ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find all configuration relevant paths regardless of OS, you can open the preferences, go to 'System' and check the various input boxes.

However, in recent versions of Inkscape, to set the default template, it is no longer necessary to know where the template folder is. After opening a new file, setting the document properties to what you need, you can just use 'File → Save Template...' and check the 'Set as default template' box in the dialog.