# Inkscape objects to marker - Engineering drawing arrow

Tags: vector, inkscape

I want to have an arrow with aspect ratio of 4 (length/width) as marker. It looks like this:[image]

Such a marker is not available in Inkscape by default. I tried drawing the same and tried the `Objects to marker` option. This object disappears. I see the object in the marker list. How to permanently save this in the list of markers?

The `Inkscape` version is 0.91.

Comment: I *think* (but haven't tested) that you can save the marker by adding it as a marker in Inscakpe's default.svg. See [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5830/inkscape-changing-default-canvas-size) about editing default.svg.

Answer (score 1):

There are some notes on adding custom markers permanently [over here](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Customize-Files.html) (go to the section "Custom Markers").

Short summary:

- Open the document containing your markers using a text editor or Inkscape's XML editor.
- Search the marker definition. It should start with `<marker …` and end with `</marker>`.
- Copy your marker definition to Inkscape's `makers.svg` *. You may want do modify the definition such that the marker adapts to stroke color, orientation, and so on.

* You can find Inkscape's configuration files on your PC by looking into Inkscape's preferences. The configuration file paths listed in `Edit > Preferences > System`. Look for the entry *Inkscape Data*. You may have to append `…/inkscape/markers/markers.svg`.