# How to make the labels bigger on the Inkscape ruler?

Tags: inkscape, configuration

The ruler at the top and left of an Inkscape document can show up in different units, controlled in "Document Properties."

But regardless of what unit I choose (I'm using inches), the *labels* on the ruler are very small and hard to read on my screen, possibly because I'm using a 4K monitor.  The rest of the interface, toolbar buttons, etc., are all fine but the ruler labels are about half the size I would want.

Here is a screenshot taken while at 1 to 1 scale (again, it's showing up large here because mine is a 4K monitor):

[image]

How can I make the labels bigger?

Comment: Tech support questions are generally off-topic here. Sorry about that. Anyway, scaling would a function of your operating system. In Windows for example, you can set your display settings to apply system zoom - which will scale the text in Inkscape's user interface. To increase the size of icons in Inkscape, use the icon size settings in Inkscape's *Preferences > Interface > Theme*. [See example here](https://imgur.com/jk5PtMp)

Comment: @BillyKerr, yeah, I found it's the subject of [an open bug report](https://gitlab.com/inkscape/inbox/-/issues/2314).  I disagree that it's a "tech support" question; otherwise [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/5830/57377) could be called off-topic just as well.  But since there's an open UI bug report about it, the current answer is sadly "this is not possible in Inkscape right now."  I still think it has value for Inkscape users, though.

Comment: Doesn't changing your system zoom settings work?

Comment: @BillyKerr doing that would affect the WHOLE interface.  And every other application, even those that are currently sized correctly on a 4K monitor.  Inkscape's interface is *mostly* sized correctly, with only a couple exceptions, most notably the ruler labels (which, exacerbating the problem, are not configurable as to size).  More details in the bug report I linked to.